# Moving file filter (Windows)

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, filter

I'm facing problem to create a specific filter to move files in Windows. The problem is, I have a file with the name **ADB.inp** and based on him the system will create others files with the name **ADB001.inp**, **ADB002.inp**, **ADB976.inp**, etc., and I need to move these files to another folder but keep the original **ADB.inp** in the folder.

Another observation is that the **ADB.inp** need to be in the same folder that the files is created. This way I can't make a filter like

> *.inp

or

> ADB*

or

> ADB0*.

Anyone knows a way that a can filter these files?

Answer (score 0):

The Windows batch file name masking capabilities are limited to `*` (any 0 or more characters), or `?` (0 or 1 character, except `.`). So it cannot be done with a single MOVE command.

The simplest solution is to use two MOVE commands - one to move everything, and then another to move the template back to the original location.

Assuming your current directory is the starting location of all the files:

```
move adb*.inp newLocation
move newLocation\adb.inp .
```

Another option is to temporarily hide the template, but that requires three steps:

```
attrib +h adb.inp
move adb*.inp newLocation
attrib -h adb.inp
```

If the template must remain (unhidden) in the correct folder at all times, then you will have to iterate the files and move them one by one:

```
for %%F in (adb*.inp) do if /i "%%F" neq adb.inp move "%%F" newLocation
```

or

```
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /a-d /b adb*.inp^|findstr /lix adb.inp') do move "%%F" newLocation
```